# angular 2 should objects/data be stored inside a service or component

Tags: angular, http-get, angular2-services, angular2-http

I have a simple todo app and it's connected to a database (example scenario).

I have a httpService which performs all the CURD operations. Now my question is:

Should the fetched todo array be stored inside the service itself or inside the todo.component? I'm asking this for consistency purposes.

I've read john papa's style guide and services are supposed to handle the logic while components only view related stuff but it doesn't really answer the questions.

In some online tutorials it was done by saving the array twice, once in the service and once in the component...

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think that this style guide answers the questions. I'll explain:

- The services are supposed to handle the logic, and as such, they are responsible to fetch the data (and not store it). But, what if you want to implement client-side caching? then you can do it in the service.
- The components are needed to store the view data (in order to display it). so most of the time you will need to store the data in a private variable so it can be displayed in the template.

Hope that it clarifies the roles.

Comment: Hey Sagi, thanks for your swift reply. To clarify, if I would deploy client-side caching, I would use the data stored inside the service to set or retrieve the data?
This would mean in order to uphold the style guide of keeping logic in services I'd need to maintain and sync two arrays?

Comment: The idea of caching is just to illustrate. Better example would be some kind of filtering, for example get only active records (in the services layer). About caching - better to implement with Observables, like here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0